# How to write the result of a complex command to a file in Bash

Tags: bash, file, find

I need to find files with `*test*` in their name, get their path and save them to a file. Here is the code:

```
find . -name *test* | xargs -I % bash -x "echo ''; readlink -f % '';"
```

It's working correctly, but I don't know how to write results to a file.
`printf "above code" >> result.txt` is not working.

What do I need to change? Or is there any way to write this in a simpler way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The redirection is added to the end of the command, no need to try and wrap it in `printf` or similar:

```
find . -name *test* | xargs -I % bash -x "echo ''; readlink -f % '';" >> result.txt
```

This doesn't work, however, as the quoting in the `bash -x` command is off. I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve exactly, but I think it could be simplified to

```
find . -name '*test*' | xargs -I% readlink -f % >> result.txt
```

Notice that I've quoted `'*test*'` to make sure it's not expanded by the shell before `find` gets to see it.

Instead of `find | xargs`, you could use `find -exec`:

```
find . -name '*test*' -exec readlink -f {} + >> result.txt
```

This has the advantage of calling `readlink` as few times as possible.

And finally, if you don't actually care about resolving symlinks (and hidden files<sup>1</sup>), but just need canonical paths, you could do it without external tools:

```
shopt -s globstar    # Requires Bash 4.0 or newer
printf "$PWD/%s\n" **/*test* >> result.txt
```

---

<sup>1</sup> If you *do* care about hidden files, you can use `shopt -s dotglob` to find them. If it is possible that there is no match at all, you can use `shopt -s nullglob` to avoid writing `**/*test*` literally to the result file.

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -name *test* | xargs -I % bash -x "echo ''; readlink -f % '';" > file.txt
```